# Object does not support this property or method VBA

Tags: excel, vba, oop

I've got a custom object called TimeZoneInfo

```
Private pTimeToConvert As Date
Private pTimeZone As String
Private pBias As Long
Private pStandardBias As Long
Private pDaylightBias As Long
Private pTimeType As TIME_ZONE
Private pTotalBias As Long
Private pStandardDate As SYSTEMTIME2
Private pDaylightDate As SYSTEMTIME2
```

Which has got 2 properties of type SYSTEMTIME2 - which is another custom class. Everything has setters and getters like below

```
''''''''''''''''''''''
' StandardTime property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get StandardDate() As Long
    StandardDate = pStandardDate
End Property
Public Property Let StandardDate(value As Long)
    pStandardDate = value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''
' DaylightDate property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get DaylightDate() As SYSTEMTIME2
    DaylightDate = pDaylightDate
End Property
Public Property Let DaylightDate(value As SYSTEMTIME2)
    pDaylightDate = value
End Property
```

However, I can't seem to assign it to the TimeZoneInfo property... I know it's definitely set to a SYSTEMTIME2 object - you can see it in the watch I've added

[image]

Am I missing something really simple here?

Comment: You need to use the `Set` keyword to set object references.

Comment: It's an object, so you need to change your `Let` property to `Set`.

Comment: @PeterT Not necessarily, just the reference: `Set DaylightDate = pDaylightDate` and `Set pDaylightDate = value`.

Comment: Also, your pStandardDate is defined as SYSTEMTIME2 but you are assigning a Long.

Comment: @BrianMStafford - Thanks  - It looks so obvious on here but I've got so many in the code it's hard to see. Good spot!

Comment: Yes, adding the Set keyword in my Getters and Setters has fixed the problem, I thought it was something simple. Thanks for the help everyone